# Why are finer details of stories related to Vaivasvata Manu are different in different conpositions/scriptures?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, matsya-purana

In Matsya Purana, Vaivasvata Manu manu is the king of Dravida Desha. He renounced the world and starts doing penance on top of Malaya mountain. Bhagavata Purana gives a similar story.

In Chapter 12.187 of Mahabharata Vana Parva Markandeya is narrating the story of Vaivasvata Manu to Yudhishtira. Here Vaivashwatha Manu is a sage and is doing penance on the banks of the Chirini River in Vishala forest.

Shouldn't Matsya Purana and Mahabharata's Descriptions match as they happened in the same Kalpa?